# Zip the root folder content without having the root at zip file

Tags: java, zip, java-io, apache-commons-io

I have the following folder Structure:

```
RootFolder
|
|
| -->F1-->F1.1-->t1.txt,t2.txt
  -->F2-->F2.2-->t3.txt
```

I have succeed,using the following code,to get the following zip file:

result.zip--> that contains:

```
RootFolder
|
|
| -->F1-->F1.1-->t1.txt,t2.txt
  -->F2-->F2.2-->t3.txt
```

I need to create a zip file that has the whole "RootFolder" content without creating a root folder"RootFolder";

I mean I need the result to be like:

result.zip--> that contains:

```
|
|
| -->F1-->F1.1-->t1.txt,t2.txt
  -->F2-->F2.2-->t3.txt
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    zipFolder("c:/new/RootFolder", "c:/new/result.zip");
}


static public void zipFolder(String srcFolder, String destZipFile)
throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    ZipOutputStream zip = null;
    FileOutputStream fileWriter = null;

    fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(destZipFile);
    zip = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter);

    addFolderToZip("", srcFolder, zip);
    zip.flush();
    zip.close();
}

static private void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile,
        ZipOutputStream zip) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

    File folder = new File(srcFile);
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {
        addFolderToZip(path, srcFile, zip);
    } else {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
        zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            zip.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}

    static public void addFolderToZip(String path, String srcFolder,
            ZipOutputStream zip) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        File folder = new File(srcFolder);

        for (String fileName : folder.list()) 

{
        if (path.equals("")) {
            addFileToZip(folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/" + fileName, zip);
        } else {
            addFileToZip(path + "/" + folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/"
                    + fileName, zip);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to add files beginning not with your root folder, but with its contents.

Something like:

```
filelist = getFileList(rootFolder)  
foreach(File f : filelist){  
    addFolderToZip(f)
}
```

Sorry for pseudocode, don't remember the original function names and can't check them right now, but they can be easily googled.

The point is to just skip creating a folder in the archive for the root folder.

Comment: I have been trying to do that but each time I end up with an exception with this messy algorithm.

Comment: :I was trying to find the simplest solution :)

Comment: and here it's :FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
   String tmp=path.replace(ROOT_FOLDER_NAME, "");

Comment: so all what I did is to add the previous line to the addFileToZip method

Comment: static private void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile,
   ZipOutputStream zip) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

  File folder = new File(srcFile);
  if (folder.isDirectory()) {
   addFolderToZip(path, srcFile, zip);
  } else {
   byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
   int len;
   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
   String tmp=path.replace(ROOT_FOLDER_NAME, "");
   zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(tmp + "/" + folder.getName()));
   while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    zip.write(buf, 0, len);
   }
   in.close();
  }
 }

Comment: @Echo You can see for yourself that that is completely illegible. Don't post large amounts of code in comments. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've written some utility methods to copy directories to a Zip file using the NIO File API (the library is Open Source):

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.3</version>  
</dependency>
```

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html#AddZipResourceSample

API: [CopyFileVisitor.copy](http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/CopyFileVisitor.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29)

Comment: I read it and it's nice.However ,according to my reading it puts the container folder as well at the zip file .. am I right!

Comment: No, it shouldn't if you omit the 2 lines in the sample with the comment "Adds the src directory name to the zip. You can omit this if you just want to copy the contents."

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find out the simplest way to solve my issue.
I resolved it be just removing the root directory name while saving at the zip file using the following:

```
String pathAfterOmittingtheRootFolder=path.replace(ROOT_FOLDER_NAME, "");
```

The complete method will be:

```
static private void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile,
        ZipOutputStream zip,String exportedRootDirectory) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

    File folder = new File(srcFile);
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {

    addFolderToZip(path, srcFile, zip,exportedRootDirectory);
} else {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
    String pathAfterOmittingtheRootFolder=path.replaceFirst(exportedRootDirectory, "");
    zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(pathAfterOmittingtheRootFolder + "/" + folder.getName()));
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        zip.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

}